# Making sure a shared resource is up-to-date

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, thread-synchronization

In an application I have a `?DateTime` and an `int` field I need to access (read/write) in multiple threads. I have read up on multiple resources, from which I learned:

1. [That some threads may use outdated values of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458173/can-a-c-sharp-thread-really-cache-a-value-and-ignore-changes-to-that-value-on-ot)
2. [`lock()`ing such a variable will solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833462/does-locking-ensure-reads-and-writes-are-flushed-from-caches-if-so-how)
3. [The microsoft docs uses an example in which such a `lock()` is not used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement#example)

From 1) and 3) I would conclude that Microsoft's example would suffer from potentially reading old data from `balance` as the lock is done on `balanceLock`.

A trimmed version of the example follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Account
{
    private readonly object balanceLock = new object();
    private decimal balance;

    public Account(decimal initialBalance) => balance = initialBalance;

    public void Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount), "The credit amount cannot be negative.");
        }

        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }
    }

    public decimal GetBalance()
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            return balance;
        }
    }
}

class AccountTest
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var account = new Account(1000);
        var tasks = new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => Update(account));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine($"Account's balance is {account.GetBalance()}");
        // Output:
        // Account's balance is 5400
    }

    static void Update(Account account)
    {
        decimal[] amounts = { 0, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 8, 5, 11, 6 };
        foreach (var amount in amounts)
        {
            account.Credit(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with the following questions:

1. Is my conclusion correct that this example would suffer from data possibly not being guaranteerd to be up-to-date? I guess not, but then, why is it the case that the `balance` variable always contains an up-to-date value, regardless of which thread is working on it? (As it is the `balanceLock` variable that is being locked, not `balance`?)
2. If this is not ensured, what methods can I use to make sure values (e.g. `?DateTime` and `int`) are always up to date between threads? I know about `lock()` and `volatile`, but the former cannot be used with value fields, and it appears `volatile` should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Some links that you might find helpful: [C# "lock" keyword: Why is an object necessary for the syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068301/c-sharp-lock-keyword-why-is-an-object-necessary-for-the-syntax), [Why do we need to lock and object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444044/why-do-we-need-to-lock-and-object-in-c/40444119), [Threading in C# - Locking](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking)

Comment: I found the answer by reading up on your last link, specifically the part on [full fences](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Full_fences) found on a different page. It appears that the issue is not so much that one thread can have a value in cpu cache that lags behind the value in main memory, but rather that (single-thread) optimizations can occur that break logic when multi-threading. Full fences prevent this, and amongst others `lock()` introduces such a full fence.
Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yeap, that's correct. One more link that you might find interesting is this: [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators).